# Combine Importrange with Split function in Google Sheets

Tags: split, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to split an import range function but it seems to only work on a single entry and not the full length of the importrange. Not sure how to fix this.

```
=SPLIT(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JXndR39CPynbs0XVsXPWClcjuUh81BGUM6TvfOys7mA/edit";"Mappen & Bestanden!A2:A");"/-_")
```

Hoping for some advice

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JXndR39CPynbs0XVsXPWClcjuUh81BGUM6TvfOys7mA/edit";"Mappen & Bestanden!A2:A");"/-_"))
```

Comment: Thank you, that indeed worked! :-)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(IMPORTRANGE("1JXndR39CPynbs0XVsXPWClcjuUh81BGUM6TvfOys7mA"; 
 "Mappen & Bestanden!A2:A"); "/-_"))
```